# How can I print out a list?

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop

I have this dictionary:

```
ANIMALS = {
"a": "ape",
"k": "kangaroo",
"@": "cat",
"h": "horse",
"l": "lamb"
}
```

and this list:

```
pelto = [
[" ", "a", " ", " ", "l"],
[" ", "k", "@", "k", " "],
["h", " ", "a", "k", " "]
]
```

I need to go through the list and find the indexes of every string in there.
After that I'd need to print everything out to something like this:

In (1, 0) there's an ape

In (4, 0) there's a lamb

In (1, 1) there's a kangaroo

In (2, 1) there's a cat

In (3, 1) there's a kangaroo

In (0, 2) there's a horse

In (2, 2) there's an ape

In (3, 2) there's a kangaroo

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

well the easy way to do this, is using the `.index()` in python (I am assuming this is python because of the dictionary), so the code that does that printing is this:

```
ANIMALS = {
  "a": "ape",
  "k": "kangaroo",
  "@": "cat",
  "h": "horse",
  "l": "lamb"
}

pelto = [
  [" ", "a", " ", " ", "l"],
  [" ", "k", "@", "k", " "],
  ["h", " ", "a", "k", " "]
]


for list in pelto:
  for item in list:
    if item is not " ":
      print(f'In ({list.index(item)}, {pelto.index(list)}) there\'s an {ANIMALS[item]}')
```

This is the result that you are waiting for:

```
In (1, 0) there's an ape
In (4, 0) there's an lamb
In (1, 1) there's an kangaroo
In (2, 1) there's an cat
In (1, 1) there's an kangaroo
In (0, 2) there's an horse
In (2, 2) there's an ape
In (3, 2) there's an kangaroo
```